# How to Access Java Code/Lib from Dynamic Feature Module in Base Module in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dynamic-feature

In [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/playcore#access_installed_modules) mentioned

> Access code and resources from installed modules

& there is a function to load native library.

```
SplitInstallHelper.loadLibrary(newContext, “my-cpp-lib”);
```

But How can I access Java/Kotlin Class Or Java Library from Installed Dynamic Feature Module?

I have checked [Call dynamic feature code from base module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528207/call-dynamic-feature-code-from-base-module) but there is no solution.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can load java/kotlin class by

```
Class cls = Class.forname("com.example.package");
```

once you are done with the dynamic feature module installation.
Then, you can instantiate using

```
Object obj = cls.newInstance();
```

Alternatively, you can have an abstract class of `com.example.package` class e.g. `ExampleAbstract`.

The final code might look like

```
ExampleAbstract obj = cls.newInstance();
```

Comment: we have used this approach earlier, but now newInstance is deprecated and getting linkage error with R8 full mode. Could anyone suggest any alternative or solution for this.